# Wordpress with ngrok redirect me for localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, ngrok

i have a site in wordpress and i want to share to my client but with ngrok when i put the link of ngrok he redirect for localhost.

I have tried relative urls plugins but still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Try with.

ngrok http 80 --host-header=rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stand alone script like the one of interconnectit.com to search and replace all urls in your database with the ngrok one.

You'll need to search :

http://localhost:8888/site (replace with your own local url)

and replace with

https://your-ngrok-url.com

Answer (score 0):

It's WP that automatically redirects the user to the "correct" domain name.

A quick fix for this is to add/edit these two lines to the wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://your-ngrok-url.ngrok.io');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://your-ngrok-url.ngrok.io');
```

Remember to remove them again, when you are done testing.